# The items in RecyclerView fit the width space irregularly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecycleView that loads review comments in a vertical LinearLayout that has layout_width attribute set to "match_parent". The adapter loads the items, but not as expected.

The first few items in my adapter do not fit the entire width space and they look visually wrong. But as I scroll down the list, it looks like the list refreshes itself and now the items are loaded fitting the entire width space.

I do not know how to best describe this problem as I have not found anything relevant concerning it. What do you think it is and how can I fix visually my RecyclerView?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWBOP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYyY0.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#2A2A2A">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/poster_image"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="230dp" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/release_date_text"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="24sp"
                            android:textStyle="italic"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                    </LinearLayout>



                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/first_star"
                            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/ic_grade_white_18px"/>

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/second_star"
                            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/ic_grade_white_18px"/>

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/third_star"
                            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/ic_grade_white_18px"/>
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/forth_star"
                            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/ic_grade_white_18px"/>
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/fifth_star"
                            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/ic_grade_white_18px"/>


                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/vote_average_textView"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="22sp"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                           />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:backgroundTint="#EEFF41"
                            android:text="ADD"
                            android:textSize="18sp"/>

                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>



            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:text="Overview" />
                <View
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="3dp"
                    android:background="#FF6F00" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/overview_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:text="Reviews"/>
                <View
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="3dp"
                    android:background="#FF6F00" />

                 <FrameLayout
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                     android:id="@+id/review_fragment_head"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:text="Trailers"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="3dp"
                    android:background="#FF6F00" />

            </LinearLayout>



        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: share your layout and reference images if possible

Comment: @FaisalNaseer ready

Comment: attach xml file.

Comment: @NoumanCh ready

Comment: First of all you had to attach the layout file of your fragment which contains RecyclerView and the inflated layout from your recyclerview as well... along the code from fragment where you are  initializing and attaching adapter to recyclerview..

Comment: and as a blind guess try  `yourRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`  soon after initialization